# background color doesn't show on hover

Tags: css, background-color

I'm working on a new responsive design and I'm having an issue with my menu that I cannot figure out. Basically I want the background of the menu item to turn white when you hover over it and the text to turn blue. Right now, the text turns blue but the background will not turn white.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="header_content">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="images/new_logo.png" class="hdr_logo">
    </div>
    <div class="main_menu">
      <ul>
        <li>ABOUT US</li>
        <li>OPERATIONS BRANCH</li>
        <li>LOGISTICS BRANCH</li>
        <li style="border-right:0;">COMMUNITY</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .header {
    background: url('images/header2.png') repeat-x top left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .header_content {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0; 
  }

  .logo {
    float:left;
    width:120px;
  }

  .main_menu {
    float:left;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 120px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 830px;
  }

  .main_menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 30px;
  }

  .main_menu li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .main_menu li:hover {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: rgb(33,47,57);
  }
```

**EDIT: Problem Resolved**

The floated li was not a block element so you could not change it's background color. As soon as I added `display:block;` to the li it resolved this issue.

Comment: just out of curiosity, is there a reason that you use the color-codes mixed in hex-format and in rgb-format?

Comment: Since this is a navigation try adding links inside your list-items and select them in your CSS instead of the **li** itself: `.main_menu a:hover { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/s3JT9/

```
.main_menu li:hover {
background-image: none;
background-color: #FFF;
color: red;
}
```

I changed the color to red to illustrate.